# Apagar um determinado repositorio do github

Tags: git, github

Como faço para apagar apenas um repositorio do github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vai no seu repositório, settings, delete repositório.
Quando vc clicar pra deletar, abrirá um pop-up em que você digitara o nome do repositório.

Comment: Vlw achei aqui tmj!!

Comment: Por nada parceiro. Tmj

Answer (score 1):

Vá no repositório, settings e delete o repositório.

Veja o tutorial:

https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1):

Vá até o repositório que deseja excluir, em seguida clique na aba **Settings**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida role até o final na tela e encontre onde está demarcado em vermelho e escrito ***Danger Zone***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Clique na ultima opção: ***Delete this repository***

Será solicitado que você confirme que deseja remover o repositório digitando o nome do mesmo.