# Como deletar um repositório excluido do GitHub?

Tags: github

Eu deletei recentemente um repositório com o nome `JS` e o [GitHub](https://github.com/) tem a opção de restaurar os repositórios (**Settings/Repositories/Deleted repositories**) excluídos o que realmente não deleta de verdade o repositório, apenas cria um **Backup** do repositório, o que eu quero é criar novamente um repositório com o nome `JS` só que o sistema não deixa retornando uma mensagem dizendo que o repositório já é existente e que eu não posso criar um repositório com o mesmo nome, então como eu faço para contornar esse problema não quero restaurar o repositório `JS` e ter que apagar arquivo por arquivo para ter um novo repositório vazio daria mais trabalho.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Apagar um determinado repositorio do github](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/331887/apagar-um-determinado-repositorio-do-github)

Comment: Não é para deletar um repositório existente e sim deletar um repositório que já foi excluído.

Comment: Não sei como você excluiu, já que o GitHub exclui permanentemente. Já tentou restaurar e excluir conforme o link mencionado?

Comment: Não colega! o GitHub não exclui permanentemente o repositório, existe a opção de restaurar o repositório excluido https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/restoring-a-deleted-repository.

Comment: Se você restaurar o repositorio, e clonar na sua máquina você consegue excluir todos os arquivos de uma única vez, depois só commitar e sincronizar, assim o repositorio fica vazio novamente. @felipecardozo

Comment: Quando diz que o "sistema" não está deixando é o próprio Github que está dando esta mensagem ou está usando alguma ferramenta para criar o repositório no Github?

Comment: Sim! o próprio GitHub.

Comment: Samuel Renan Gonçalves Vaz, sim! só que como mencionado na pergunta daria mais trabalho visto que procuro um solução mais ágil de se fazer, isso porque futuramente pode ser que ocorra novamente e terei que repetir os mesmos passos e também pode ter outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não tem como excluir o repositório antes dos 90 dias do backup, mas aconselho começar o projeto do zero para não ter que esperar tanto.

Basta iniciar um novo projeto local:

```
git init
```

Configurar a origin do seu repositório:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Adicionar um readme ou .gitignore e fazer o commit inicial

```
git add .
git commit -m "Primeiro commit"
```

Remover o o branch do master dos protegido, o que é ensinado [aqui](https://help.github.com/pt/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-protected-branches)!
Por ultimo forçar o envio (Perdera todo histórico do master):

git push origin -f

Caso tenha outros branch remova-os do remoto com:

```
git push origin :nome-da-branch
```

ou

```
git push origin --delete nome-da-branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Não tem muito o que fazer se quer reaproveitar o nome do repo, vai dar um trabalho.

Primeiro você vai ter que restaurar o repo no Github e depois fazer um clone pra sua máquina.
Depois vai ter que deletar a branch master na sua máquina da seguinte maneira:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git # seu repo

git branch nova-branch # cria a nova-branch
git checkout nova-branch # troca para a nova-branch
git branch -D master # deleta localmente a branch master
```

Depois vai fazer o push da nova-branch para o Github:

```
git push origin nova-branch # faz o push para o Github
```

Em seguida, vá ao Github e acessa as configurações do repositório em: Settings -> Branches, e troque a Default Branch para nova-branch.

Após isso, você vai conseguir fazer push da remoção da branch master:

```
git push origin :master # faz o push da remoção da branch master
```

Se quiser, agora você pode gerar uma nova branch master e trocar o default no Github.

Comment: Precisa dessa dança toda mesmo?
Eu só começaria um projeto novo local, adicionaria o remoto, e usaria um `git push -f origin master` - e depois, é exclui os outros branches do projeto antigo.

Answer (score 0):

Os respositórios ficam disponíveis por 90 dias. Depois desse prazo será definitivamente removido.

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/deleting-a-repository). Abaixo o trecho extraído.

```
Please also keep in mind that:

Deleting a private repository will delete all of its forks.
Deleting a public repository will not delete its forks.
You can restore some deleted repositories within 90 days. For more information, see "Restoring a deleted repository."
```

Então as opções são essas:

- aguardar pelos 90 dias
- ou renomear o projeto e então deletar

Comment: Isto mesmo @PeterSmith, o único jeito é deletar e esperar os 90 dias. Questão de segurança. Evita deleção acidental. Ou troque o nome ou espere os 90 dias.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode começar um novo repositório do Github do zero, com outro nome. Após passados os dias em que o repositório deletado fica "em backup" você renomeia repositório do Github.

As URLs do Remoto não precisam necessariamente ser atualizados pois o Github redireciona a URL para o novo nome do repositório, mas é aconselhável atualizar por boas práticas.

Pra atualizar a URL do remoto é só rodar:

```
git remote origin set-url <nova-url>
```

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, como visto o GitHub tem essa política de segurança de manter um histórico do seu repositório por 90 dias antes de realmente deletar.
Uma ideia para contornar isso seria, antes de deletar, alterar o nome do repositório e aí sim deleta-lo, assim o nome que você quer ficaria disponível para ser usado.
No seu caso, como você já deletou o repositório, você poderia simplesmente restaura-lo, renomear, deletar novamente.
Acredito que seja a melhor opção já que você não quer ter que apagar todos os arquivos para continuar usando o mesmo repo.